# How to diagnose launch-time errors in Firefox that my extension causes?

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I open Firefox and then immediately the Error Console, I see:

```
Timestamp: 01/24/2013 09:43:33 AM
Error: this.docShell is null
Source File: chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml
Line: 323
```

If I dsable/remove the extension I am developing, that error does not show at launch.

I've attempted to locate the cause of this error by removing different sections of my extension's code and relaunching, but that has not proved fruitful.  I need at minimum a stack trace to know what is referencing `this.docShell` and what `this` is in that context.  And hopefully, what I am referencing/calling that ends up eventually making that bad reference.

Comment: Do you have <overlay> or <browser> in you xul file?

Comment: Lots of overlays.  JS components, JS modules.  Lots of things going on.